# Low rep user able to post a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

I came across something very odd in the LQ-queue today. There's a "you're welcome" answer from a 1-rep user that needs to be deleted. While looking for what "thank you" this was meant to answer, I discovered that - somehow - this 1-rep user was able to write a comment (that offered the helpful suggestion)?

[developing alarm repeating days list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247732/developing-alarm-repeating-days-list)

I clicked on this user's link and see that s/he's been a member for over two years. Is that why it was possible to comment? Or what's up, here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A moderator would need to confirm this, but it seems that the comment was originally posted as an answer, and then converted to a comment by a moderator or an automated process as described by Oded.

Comment: Likely this was an _automatically_ converted answer - low quality answers like this (a bit of text + a link) can be auto converted to a comment. I don't see a corresponding deleted answer by the user (there was another answer by the user later on, but I deleted that one, and it wasn't the same text).

Comment: Right, thanks for the info :-)

Comment: @Oded "low quality answers like this (a bit of text + a link) can be auto converted to a comment". What is the criteria for the same?

Comment: @CinCout - basically that. A few words and a link. If there is nothing else, it can get auto converted.

Comment: Is it completely automated? Or requires moderator intervention? Asking because LQP queue is full of such posts. Wondering why they aren't automatically converted!

Comment: @Oded When you say automatic do you mean it is a process ran by community or it is automatic as a mod can just click a button and bam the answer is deleted and converted to a comment?

Comment: @NathanOliver I think that automatic means here "without any human intervention".

Comment: @Oded How does the system automatically determine which answers to convert to comments? Ones with a certain # of VLQ flags? or something?

Comment: @TylerH - it happens when they are posted. If they are very short, only a few words (and possibly a link) they get converted.

Comment: @Oded And, from the info in the other question, the link must be "internal" (SO), not external, which would explain why there are still so many in the LQ and NAA queue. Many of those links are to outside sources...